# In which AWS service should I deploy my react app

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, deployment

I'am currently searching the best and cheapest solution to host my dashboard in react.js
I wanna host it using one of the aws services.
My configuration: The dashboard is already built and make calls to a separated API hosted on EC2 and I don't want to serve my dashboard from it. The dashboard will receive a SMALL amount of requests since it's not dedicated to clients.
I have already fews solutions in my head but I never used them so I'am writing this post to ask your recommendation from your experiences.
Potential solution:

AWS S3

AWS EC2

AWS AMPLIFY

AWS E BEANSTALK

I guess that the amplify is a faster solution amongst them but my dashboard is already using an existing backend.

What are your recommendation about this ? what is the best cheapiest solution in this configuration

Thank you,

VK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 + CloudFront is always a good option to serve your front-end. Since you are not going to provide this service to your client, we can simply use S3 web hosting is fine.

Don't forget to set your CORS and if you are using S3 web hosting without Cloudfront, your bucket name will need to equal to your domain name.

The reason I don't recommend you use other solutions is I believe you know how Serverless affects us. I assumed you don't want to manage the additional machine. Therefore, S3 would be your best solution, it also supports header/logging/versioning.

Comment: Thank's for your asnwer, it is cheap yes.  I will check this out and see how it works with the react-routing

Comment: @VK_ any updates ? I am facing the exact same situation and would love to hear your experience.